# 第三者が質問に外部サイトのコードを追加する際には慎重になるべきでは？

Tags: 討議

質問者さんが質問にコードを含めず、外部サイトにコードをアップロードしてそのURLだけ知らせることがあります。それへの対処として、第三者が質問を編集してそのコードを追加する方法があります。
これは以前より行われていますが、もう少し慎重になされるべきだと感じますので、以下で理由を述べます。

#### 許可

外部のソースコードなどをコピーする際には、それが質問者さんの物であるように見えても、まずは本人の許可といいますか意思の確認があった方がよいと思います。著作権云々までは無くとも、色々と都合がありますので。
例えば、短いコードであっても、変数名や関数名で「身ばれ」する可能性があります。スタック・オーバーフローは一度でも載せると消せませんので、他サイトとは事情が異なります。

#### 質問がナレッジの集積に寄与する形になるか

質問のスタイルとして、作業中のコードを見せて直して貰うというものも有っていいし、それはそれで歓迎されるべきと思います。
しかし、そういう形の質問は質問者には直接に役に立つものの、スタック・オーバーフローのもう一つの目的である、ナレッジの集積には寄与しづらい傾向があります。
質問者さんが積極的にこのスタイルを選択していない場合、あえて第三者が作業中のコードをコピーする場合は強い理由が必要だと考えます。例えば、それが無ければ意味不明である、といった場合です。

---

（以上は [引数の数値に応じて実行する処理を増やしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48478/3054) に行なわれた編集を見て書きました。この編集はモデレータさんによるものだったので議論に出し易いタイミングと思いましたが、一般論として以前から気になっていたことです）

Comment: 「スタック・オーバーフローは一度でも載せると消せません」という部分は間違いです。モデレーターによる [redact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132119/341401) によって消すことができます。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 「自分でひっそりと消せない」と言い換えてもいいですが、「ここを消して欲しいらしい」という事が他人に解ってしまうこと自体が問題になりうるわけです。

Comment: あえて原理的に言えば、SO 上のすべてのドキュメントは CC-by-SA であるので、逆に、 CC-by-SA compatible なソースのコピーないし引用でないかぎり、第三者がコードを追加することはできないはずです。一つの観点として。。

Answer (score 1):

私の編集でコード部分を転載する前に一度コメントで確認すべきだった、というのはその通りだったと思います。実は編集前私も少し躊躇したのですが、コード部分がそこまで特殊でなかったのと、そこまで長くなかったために確認なしに転載してしまいました。

転載する際に気になるのは、ライセンスが CC BY-SA になることや、mjy さんがおっしゃるところの「身ばれ」でしょう。この意味での確認は、明らかそうでもすべきでした。

しかしナレッジの集積に寄与するかどうかについては、そこまで神経質にならなくとも良いのではないでしょうか。どのような質問形式がナレッジの集積により多く寄与するのかは、そこまで自明ではないと感じています。[すべての質問が、コードを含めることで利益を得るわけではありません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)が、利益になるかどうかはコードを見ないと分かりにくいです。

このため基本的には「建設的な回答がしやすいよう、質問をより具体的にして欲しい」という立場から、私はソースコードがあれば見たいと思っています。最終的にコードまでは必要なかったということであれば、閲覧時のノイズになるので解決後に編集するということはあるでしょう。

もしその質問を別のやり方で書いたときナレッジがより集積できると感じたのであれば、回答をより一般的な形に対応できるよう書くというやり方や、自己回答の形で別の Q&A を投稿するというやり方があります。

**まとめ**：何かしらの事情がないか確認することは必要でしょう。ナレッジの集積しやすさを気にするのであれば、解決後に編集したり、回答を工夫したりする方法があります。

Comment: 末尾に挙げた個別の件に関しては、やってあげられる事をやってあげるるのは親切な事ですし、明らかに仕事のコードなどでも無く、許可を取らなかったことに大きな問題は無かったと思います。

Comment: 私が大きな問題を感じているのは、ナレッジの集積の方でして、この点に関してスタック・オーバーフローはだんだん悪くなってきていると思います。
回答者側にとにかく質問を元に回答を書いてみよう、とう意欲が失われて来ていて、要件を聞き出してFixするというサイクルを早く回すことに偏って来ていると感じます。
その場合には、「もう実際のコード全部出して」というのが一番早いわけですが、それで良い Q&A になることは少ないです。
ちょっと具体性に欠ける質問だからこそ生れる力作といってよいような回答も少なくなった気がしています。なんとなく傾向を感じている、というだけですが。

Comment: @mjy さん、なるほど、そこに関しては私は昔をあまり知らないので何とも言い難いですね……。本家 Stack Overflow 等での類似議論が無いか探してみます。